# pyspark round function throws "Invalid argument, not a string or column" error

Tags: pyspark

I have an ELT process that after the dataset has been created, the code below is executed to count the rows to determine the number of partitions.

```
provider_out = get_provider(spark)
numofpartitions = round(provider_out.count()/10000000)
```

This numofpartitions variable is used later to partition the data equally when writing to the destition as shown below.

```
provider_out.repartition(numofpartitions).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(dest_path)
```

I'm running into a problem when the numofpartions variable gets calculated and throws the "Invalid argument, not a string or column: 45.0838586 of type <class 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function." error.  I know this can occur when the result gets passed as an object, but it's a single float value that is being rounded.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: it seems you've imported pyspark sql functions without an alias -- are they being imported as `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`? if yes, the `round()` from pyspark sql functions is being called instead of python's native `round()`. TIP -- always use alias while using pyspark sql functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've imported pyspark sql functions without an alias. Are they being imported as `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`? if yes, the `round()` from pyspark sql functions is being called instead of python's native `round()`. *TIP - It's a good practice to import pyspark sql functions with an alias.*

pyspark's [`round()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.round.html#pyspark-sql-functions-round) requires a column name (`col()` or `lit()`) to process and, thus, throws an error when given an integer.

See below test.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

round(data1_rdd.count()/10)
# 0

func.round(data1_rdd.count()/10)  # you inadvertently called this
# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0.2 of type <class 'float'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Comment: Thanks that was precisely it.  I inherited this project where best practices weren't really followed and I'm relatively new to python, so understanding this really helps me in cleaning up this code.